# Problema con retrieve en Firebase

Tags: firebase, react-native

He estado revisando mi código, y pareciera ser que tengo todo bien, y no logro percibir si tengo algún erro.

Estoy tratando de recuperar una colección con documentos de una sola variable. Seguí la documentación de Firebase e hice alguna adecuaciones en mi función para que funcionara, pero nada hace que funcione.

```js
getFirebase = async () => {
    var firebase = require("firebase");

    // REQUIRED FOR SIDE-EFFECTS
    require("firebase/firestore");

    var myapp = firebase.firestore()

    // RETRIEVING FROM FIREBASE
    var reportsFirebase = [];
    miapp.collection("reports").get().then((querySnapshot) => {
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            console.log(`${doc.id} => ${doc.data()}`);
            var title = JSON.stringify(doc.data().title)
            var reportFirebase = {
                title: title,
            }
            reportsFirebase.push(reportFirebase);
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Estás definiendo:

```
var myapp
```

Sin embargo, tienes un error porque derivas la función de `.collection` de `miapp` la cual no existe.

Solo cambia `miapp` por `myapp`

Saludos.